# Is there a way to hint to the compiler to use some kind of default generic type when using Option::None?

Tags: generics, rust, option-type, traits

I need a function that gets an `Option` of an generic type `T` that implements the trait `std::iter::IntoIterator`.
A naive implementation could look like the following (yes, the unwrap would panic on `None`):

```
fn main() {
    let v = vec![1i32, 2, 3];
    print_iter(Some(v));
    print_iter(None);
}

fn print_iter<T: IntoIterator<Item = i32>>(v: Option<T>) {
    for e in v.unwrap() {
        println!("{}", e);
    }
}
```

Test on [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d7f70d95df7327100e96b3c17ffcb5ce).

This works as expected for `Some(...)`, but fails for `None` with:

```
error[E0282]: type annotations needed
 --> src/main.rs:4:5
  |
4 |     print_iter(None);
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^ cannot infer type for `T`
```

Obviously the type of `T` is unknown in those cases. One could use `print_iter::<Vec<i32>>(None);` but this does not feel really idiomatic, because this gives some arbitrary type that isn't based on anything...

Is there any way to hint to the compiler that I don't care for `None` or use some kind of default?

Comment: This should be part of a library and it is used as some kind of flag. If the user does not want to provide an input, it is handy to use the literal `None` instead of defining a typed variable first.

Comment: Since `Option` is an `IntoIterator` you can send an empty iterator for your case like this : `print_iter(Some(None))` , [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there any way to hint to the compiler that I don't care for `None` or use some kind of default?

You can implement your own non-generic value to serve as the default. For starters, let's assume `print_iter` didn't accept `Option<T>`, but an enum of its own:

```
enum PrintArg<T> {
    Ignore,
    Use(T),
}

fn print_iter<T: IntoIterator<Item = i32>>(v: PrintArg<T>) {
    if let PrintArg::Use(v) = v {
        for e in v {
            println!("{}", e);
        }
    }
}
```

This doesn't solve the problem yet, because if you pass `PrintArg::Ignore` to `print_iter()`, you are back at square one - the compiler is unable to to infer the `T`. But with your own type, you can easily change `print_iter` to accept anything that can be *converted* [into](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.Into.html) `PrintArg`:

```
fn print_iter<T, V>(v: T)
where
    T: Into<PrintArg<V>>,
    V: IntoIterator<Item = i32>,
{
    if let PrintArg::Use(v) = v.into() {
        for e in v {
            println!("{}", e);
        }
    }
}
```

With this modification, you can create a dummy non-generic `Ignore` value and use the [`From`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.From.html?search=) trait to define its conversion to a `PrintArg::Ignore<T>` with `T` of your choice - for example:

```
struct Ignore;

impl From<Ignore> for PrintArg<Vec<i32>> {
    fn from(_v: Ignore) -> Self {
        PrintArg::Ignore
    }
}
```

As `Ignore` is non-generic, its use doesn't require (or accept) a `<T>`. While we did have to invent a type for `PrintArg<T>` in the `From` trait implementation, we never construct it, so it's irrelevant which one we choose, as long as it satisfies the `IntoIterator` bound.

Of course, you'll still want to be able to invoke `print_iter()` with `Some(...)`, so you'll also define a conversion of `Option<T>` to `PrintArg<T>`:

```
impl<T> From<Option<T>> for PrintArg<T> {
    fn from(v: Option<T>) -> Self {
        match v {
            Some(v) => PrintArg::Use(v),
            None => PrintArg::Ignore,
        }
    }
}
```

With these in place, your API is clean, allowing `main()` to look like this ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e2df16413dd187d24dc0cec84975f221)):

```
fn main() {
    let v = vec![1i32, 2, 3];
    print_iter(Some(v));
    print_iter(Ignore);
}
```

Comment: This is probably a better answer than mine.

Comment: OP question makes sense only because the `print_iter` function, in fact, takes several parameters (which wasn't obvious before edit and comment). And options rarely come alone (and you don't want to pass several flags to a function). So it's possible the real convenient solution is to build a more complex struct holding several options. But this answer is probably a sensible first step to the undescribed real question.

Comment: @user4815162342, DenysSéguret Thanks to both of you for the fast response! Sorry for not having a clear question in the beginning. I'm new to rust so nomenclature and phrasing my problems is still a struggle for me.

Answer (score 3):

There's no problem with the value `None`.

There's just a problem when your variable type can't be inferred which doesn't usually occur. The only case where there's a problem is when you directly pass `None`, and have no typed variable.

You can specify the type using the turbo fish:

```
print_iter::<Vec<i32>>(None);
```

But you don't usually need to; your normal cases would rather be like this:

```
let a: Option<Vec<i32>> = None;
print_iter(a);
```

or

```
print_iter(my_options.a);
```

and both constructs are without problem.

**Now** (following question edit), if you really want to be able to pass `None` without precising the type, for example as a literal flag, then you can define a macro:

```
macro_rules! pi {
    (None) => {
         // here we handle the call as a nop but
         //  other behaviors are possible, like
         //  calling the function with a type
         //  specified with a turbofish
    };
    ($a:expr) => {
        print_iter($a)
    };
}

fn main() {
    let v = vec![1i32, 2, 3];
    pi!(Some(v));
    pi!(None);
}

fn print_iter<T: IntoIterator<Item = i32>>(v: Option<T>) {
    for e in v.unwrap() {
        println!("{}", e);
    }
}
```